# Display Images using RSS Feed in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, xcode, rss

I want to display images from the url

[RSS Feed](https://www.nasa.gov/rss/dyn/breaking_news.rss)

I am using table view controller in my Objective c project..I am able to display text and links perfectly but not able to display images from the Feed url

I am using the following code

```
**TableViewController.h**
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface TableViewController : UITableViewController <NSXMLParserDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *TableView;

@end
```

**TableViewController.m**

```
#import "TableViewController.h"
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface TableViewController (){

    NSXMLParser *parser;
    NSMutableArray *feeds;
    NSMutableDictionary *item;
    NSMutableString *title;
    NSMutableString *link;
    NSString *element;
    NSString *imageType;
     NSString *imageUrl;
}

@end

@implementation TableViewController


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    feeds=[[NSMutableArray alloc ] init];
      NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.nasa.gov/rss/dyn/breaking_news.rss"];
    parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
    [parser setDelegate:self];
    [parser setShouldResolveExternalEntities:NO];
    [parser parse];


}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {



    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {



    return feeds.count;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = [[feeds objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"title"];





  //  cell.imageView.image=  [[feeds objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"title"];

    return cell;
}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {

    element = elementName;

    if ([element isEqualToString:@"item"]) {

        item = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        title = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        link = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    }


    if ([element isEqualToString:@"enclosure"]) {
        imageType   =   [attributeDict objectForKey:@"type"];
        imageUrl    =   [attributeDict objectForKey:@"url"];

    }


}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {

    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"item"]) {

        [item setObject:title forKey:@"title"];
        [item setObject:link forKey:@"link"];


        [item setObject:imageType forKey:@"imageType"];
        [item setObject:imageUrl forKey:@"imageUrl"];


        [feeds addObject:[item copy]];

    }

}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string {

    if ([element isEqualToString:@"title"]) {
        [title appendString:string];
    } else if ([element isEqualToString:@"link"]) {
        [link appendString:string];
    }
}

-(void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser {

    [self.tableView reloadData];
}


-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showDetail"]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        NSString *string = [feeds[indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"link"];
        [[segue destinationViewController] setUrl:string];
    }

}




@end
```

Please help me to display images I am stuck with this.Thanks

Comment: where u have set imageurl to cell image ?  have u created any imageview on tableview cell

Comment: @SKT yes!! i want to display image on the tableview Cell

Comment: check answer and just add simple image in it and then check

Answer (score 1):

Use this way :

```
    if (cell == nil) 

    {

        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"identifier"];
        UIImageview imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(150, 0, 48, 48)];
imgView.tag = 100;


//ssame way create a label
  UILabel titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 40)];
titlelabel.tag = 102
[cell.contentview addsubview:imgview];
[cell.contentview addsubview:titlelabel];
    }

     UIImageview mImgView = (uiimageview *)[cell  viewwithtag:100];   
UILabel mLabel = (uilabel*)cell  viewwithtag:102];

//set data 
mlabel = //your label
mimgviw.imge = imageurl
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put this line to your `UITableViewCell`

```
 NSString *imgUrl = [[feeds objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"imageUrl"];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imgUrl]]];

    cell.imageView.image = image;
```